# PHP PDO select data using class

Tags: php, class, pdo

I have created a class here for get the data, and it is working fine, but I don't know is it a right code? Anyone can just check the code for me ?

```
<?php
class SingleData {
    public $tbName;
    public $id;
    public $col;
    public function viewData($tbName,$id,$col){
        $start = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;charset=utf8mb4',"root","pass");
        $con = $start->prepare("SELECT $col FROM $tbName WHERE id=?");
        $con->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $con->execute();
        $result=$con->fetchColumn();
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

and this is how I call the data

```
$data=new SingleData;
echo $data->viewData('user',1,'FName'). " ";
echo $data->viewData('user',1,'LName'). </br>;
echo $data->viewData('user',1,'Job'). </br>;
```

and the result will be:

```
John Smith
Sales Manager
```

Comment: just change this $data=new SingleData();

Comment: the rest is  ok ?

Comment: yes, i think rest is okay please try and let me know if there's any issue

Comment: How can I do a __construct from the code above ? just kind of lost

Comment: Are you just trying to return all data from one table? Your code is pretty jumbled

Comment: Also, what is $tbName referring back to? You shouldn't place your table name into a variable.

Comment: Your question belongs to a codereview@SO site, not here. But here is a short resume: Frankly, this class makes no sense, either by intention and by implementation: You don't need a class for such a task, it's wrong use of OOP. And you should never connect to a database more than once.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Personally, I would do something along the lines of this:

```
class SingleData {
    private $_db;
    public $tbName, $id, $col;

    public function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user;charset=utf8mb4", "root", "pass");
        } catch(e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function viewData($tbName, $id, $col){
        $con = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT $col FROM $tbName WHERE id=?");
        $con->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $con->execute();

        $result=$con->fetchColumn();
        return $result;
    }
}
```